# How to create additional rows for each combination of values in 2 columns based on data in third column in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

```
data = [
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-25', 1, 20, 11),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-04', 0, 10, 10),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-01', 0, 10, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-10', 0, 25, 10),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-02', None, 12, None)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
```

[image]

**Input dataset:**

And as you can see I have columns:

- id - id of client
- survey - date of survey (data type object)
- event - date of event (data type object)
- col1, col2, col3 - rest of variables (in real dataset I have many more)

**Requirements:**

And I need to for each combination of values in columns id, survey I need to create rows with:

- the same values in column: id, survey
- NaN values in columns: col1, col2, col3
- dates (data type object) in column event which do not exist for a given combination values in id, survey going back to the date in the survey column of the previous month (if combination id = 1 and survey = '2023-10-10' I need to create rows with dates to have in column event values from 2023-10-10 till 2023-09-10 (remember each month need to have 31 days!! :) )
- we assume that each month has 31 days (it does not matter how many days a month really has)

**Example of needed output:**

For each combination of values in id, survey I create rows with all days 31 days back from the date in the survey column which do not exist in column event for each combination of values in columns: id, survey. And I put NaN in all created rows in columns: col1, col2, col3

```
data = [
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-25', 1, 20, 11),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-04', 0, 10, 10),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-09', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-08', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-07', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-06', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-05', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-03', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-02', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-01', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-31', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-30', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-29', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-28', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-27', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-26', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-24', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-23', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-22', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-21', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-20', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-19', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-18', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-17', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-16', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-15', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-14', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-13', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-12', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-11', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-10', None, None, None),
    
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-01', 0, 10, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-05', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-04', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-03', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-02', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-31', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-30', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-29', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-28', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-27', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-26', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-25', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-24', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-23', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-22', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-21', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-20', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-19', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-18', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-17', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-16', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-15', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-14', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-13', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-12', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-11', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-10', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-09', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-08', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-07', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-06', None, None, None),
    (1, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-05', None, None, None),
    
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-10', 0, 25, 10),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-02', None, 12, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-13', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-12', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-11', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-09', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-08', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-07', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-06', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-05', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-04', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-03', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-01', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-31', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-30', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-29', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-28', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-27', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-26', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-25', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-24', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-23', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-22', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-21', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-20', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-19', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-18', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-17', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-16', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-15', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-14', None, None, None),
    (2, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-13', None, None, None) 
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
```

How can I achieve this kind of output in Python Pandas ?

Comment: "*we assume that each month has 31 days*" -> why this weird requirement?

Comment: mozway - because for each combination of values from the columns: id, survey there must be the same number of rows in the output :)

Comment: mozway - because for each combination of values from the columns: id, survey there must be the same number of rows in the output :) For example if some combination of id = 1 and survey = 2023-10-10 I need to have for that combination values in column 'event' from 2023-10-10 till 2023-09-10 with assumption that September has 31 days and same model for rest of examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to your requirements, this solution could be slow without parallelization (it depends on your number of groups (id, survey)):

```
# If it's not already the case
df['survey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['survey'])
df['event'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event'])

def fill_event(df):
    # Find start and end days
    end = df.name[1]
    start = end - pd.DateOffset(months=1)

    # Create range
    start = [f"{start.to_period('M')}-{day:02}" for day in range(end.day, 32)]
    end = [f"{end.to_period('M')}-{day:02}" for day in range(1, end.day)]
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [df.name[0]]*31, 'survey': [df.name[1]]*31,
                        'event': start + end})

    return (pd.concat([df.astype({'survey': str, 'event': str}), df1])
              .drop_duplicates('event').sort_values('event'))
    
out = (df.groupby(['id', 'survey'], as_index=False, sort=False)
         .apply(fill_event).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    id     survey       event  col1  col2  col3
0    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-11   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-12   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-14   NaN   NaN   NaN
..  ..        ...         ...   ...   ...   ...
88   2 2023-02-13  2023-02-08   NaN   NaN   NaN
89   2 2023-02-13  2023-02-09   NaN   NaN   NaN
90   2 2023-02-13  2023-02-10   0.0  25.0  10.0
91   2 2023-02-13  2023-02-11   NaN   NaN   NaN
92   2 2023-02-13  2023-02-12   NaN   NaN   NaN

[93 rows x 6 columns]

>>> out.head(31)
    id     survey       event  col1  col2  col3
0    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-11   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-12   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-14   NaN   NaN   NaN
5    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-15   NaN   NaN   NaN
6    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-16   NaN   NaN   NaN
7    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-17   NaN   NaN   NaN
8    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-18   NaN   NaN   NaN
9    1 2023-10-10  2023-09-19   NaN   NaN   NaN
10   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-20   NaN   NaN   NaN
11   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-21   NaN   NaN   NaN
12   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-22   NaN   NaN   NaN
13   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-23   NaN   NaN   NaN
14   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-24   NaN   NaN   NaN
15   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-25   1.0  20.0  11.0
16   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-26   NaN   NaN   NaN
17   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-27   NaN   NaN   NaN
18   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-28   NaN   NaN   NaN
19   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-29   NaN   NaN   NaN
20   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-30   NaN   NaN   NaN
21   1 2023-10-10  2023-09-31   NaN   NaN   NaN
22   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-01   NaN   NaN   NaN
23   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-02   NaN   NaN   NaN
24   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-03   NaN   NaN   NaN
25   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-04   0.0  10.0  10.0
26   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
27   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-06   NaN   NaN   NaN
28   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-07   NaN   NaN   NaN
29   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-08   NaN   NaN   NaN
30   1 2023-10-10  2023-10-09   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Corralien - The output is very good, just as I expected, but you are right, with a larger set of data (more pairs of values from columns: id, survey) it takes a very long time to count, can you see the possibility of some optimization to make it count faster? :)

Comment: How many groups (id, survey) do you have?

Comment: Corralien - even though it is slow, I don't think it's worth your time to optimise it and it's not a tragedy in terms of performance, thank you very much for your help! I gave the best answer :)

Comment: Thanks :-) Take a look to [Pandarallel](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel). With little effort you can use `groupby().parallel_apply()`. You can also use [Modin](https://github.com/modin-project/modin)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you desire, but what I would do is:

- Separate each ID as separate dataframe, you can achieve it trough creating dictonary of dataframes like:

  ```
    id_list = list(df['id'].unique())
    DataFramedict = {elem: pd.DataFrame() for elem in id_list}

    for key in DataFramedict.keys():
        DataFramedict[key] = df[:][df['id'] == key]
  ```
- Create date range frame as:

  ```
    dates = pd.date_range(max(df['survey']) - 31, max(df['survey']))
  ```
- for each id in for loop, add date range with pd.concat method (it will add only dates, if you will name oclumn the same, for the rest of the columns it will place "NaN")

  ```
    for id in id_list:
        DataFramedict[id] = pd.concat([DataFramedict[id], dates])
  ```

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: jeste_artyste, I have error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str in line: id_list = list(data['id'].unique()) nut event if I change data type of id from str to int I have error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series in line: DataFrame[key] = data[:][data['ID'] == key] and remember that my input DataFrame is df not data, could you repair your code, please ?

Comment: please use names of DataFrame (df) and names of columns from my example, because I do not have column name 'date'

Comment: I edited with correct column names, does you 'survey' datatype is datetime? or it's visible as object?

Comment: jeste_artyste, both survey and event are data type object and it has to stay as object in output :)

Comment: using code from the first bullet point: DataFrame[key] = data[:][df['id'] == key] in this line I have error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Series - is that code work on my example data frame from question ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry was answering beetwen writing my code :D It should be fine now, I editted response - it's working for me now