# How to create new rows in Data Frame based on values in 2 columns managing also values in another columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have Data Frame in Python Pandas like below:

**Input data: (columns survey and event are object date type)**

```
data = [
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-25', 1, 20, 11),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-04', 0, 10, 10),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-01', 0, 10, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-10', 0, 25, 10),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-02', None, 12, None)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
```

[image]

**Requirements:**

And I need to create new rows for each combination of values in columns: id, survey. New rows have to:

1. For each combination of values in: id, survey create dates in the event column that do not exist for the given combination of values in: id, survey **going back 31 days from date in survey column**, for example if the combination id = 1 and survey = '2023-05-05' I need to have date rows  in the event column from 2023-05-04 to 2023-04-04, i.e. 31 days backwards for that combination of: id, survey
2. each new row need to has NaN values in columns: col1, col2, col3
3. each new row need to has same values in columns: nps, target, score for each combination of values in: id, survey

**Example output:**

So, as a result I need to have something like below:

```
data = [
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-25', 1, 20, 11),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-04', 0, 10, 10),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-09', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-08', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-07', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-06', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-05', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-03', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-02', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-01', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-30', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-29', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-28', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-27', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-26', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-24', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-23', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-22', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-21', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-20', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-19', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-18', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-17', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-16', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-15', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-14', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-13', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-12', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-11', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-10', None, None, None),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-09', None, None, None),
    
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-01', 0, 10, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-04', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-03', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-02', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-30', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-29', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-28', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-27', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-26', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-25', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-24', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-23', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-22', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-21', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-20', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-19', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-18', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-17', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-16', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-15', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-14', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-13', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-12', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-11', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-10', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-09', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-08', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-07', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-06', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-05', None, None, None),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-04-04', None, None, None),

    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-10', 0, 25, 10),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-02', None, 12, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-12', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-11', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-09', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-08', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-07', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-06', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-05', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-04', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-03', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-01', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-31', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-30', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-29', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-28', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-27', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-26', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-25', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-24', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-23', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-22', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-21', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-20', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-19', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-18', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-17', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-16', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-15', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-14', None, None, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-01-13', None, None, None),
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Comment: How is this different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77393610/9473764)?

Comment: Nick: 1. in the question you quoted I was going back 31 assuming each month has 31 days, in the current question I am simply going back 31 days 2. in the question you quoted there was no condition that each new row needed to have same values in columns: nps, target, score for each combination of values in: id, survey

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. There's a lot of data so it wasn't immediately obvious.

Comment: Nick, do you have some idea, how to solve that problem in Python Pandas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["event"] = pd.to_datetime(df["event"])
df["survey"] = pd.to_datetime(df["survey"])


def fn(g):
    g = g.set_index("event")

    d = g["survey"].min()
    g = (
        g.reindex(pd.date_range(d - pd.Timedelta(days=31), d))
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={"index": "event"})
    )
    g[["id", "nps", "target", "score", "survey"]] = (
        g[["id", "nps", "target", "score", "survey"]].ffill().bfill()
    )
    return g


df = df.groupby(["id", "survey"], group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
        event   id  nps  target  score     survey  col1  col2  col3
0  2023-04-04  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2023-04-05  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  2023-04-06  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  2023-04-07  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2023-04-08  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
5  2023-04-09  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  2023-04-10  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  2023-04-11  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
8  2023-04-12  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
9  2023-04-13  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
10 2023-04-14  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
11 2023-04-15  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
12 2023-04-16  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
13 2023-04-17  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
14 2023-04-18  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
15 2023-04-19  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
16 2023-04-20  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
17 2023-04-21  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
18 2023-04-22  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
19 2023-04-23  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
20 2023-04-24  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
21 2023-04-25  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
22 2023-04-26  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
23 2023-04-27  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
24 2023-04-28  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
25 2023-04-29  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
26 2023-04-30  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
27 2023-05-01  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   0.0  10.0   NaN
28 2023-05-02  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
29 2023-05-03  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
30 2023-05-04  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
31 2023-05-05  1.0  5.0     0.0   0.58 2023-05-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
0  2023-09-09  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2023-09-10  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  2023-09-11  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  2023-09-12  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2023-09-13  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
5  2023-09-14  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  2023-09-15  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  2023-09-16  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
8  2023-09-17  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
9  2023-09-18  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
10 2023-09-19  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
11 2023-09-20  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
12 2023-09-21  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
13 2023-09-22  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
14 2023-09-23  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
15 2023-09-24  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
16 2023-09-25  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   1.0  20.0  11.0
17 2023-09-26  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
18 2023-09-27  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
19 2023-09-28  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
20 2023-09-29  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
21 2023-09-30  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
22 2023-10-01  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
23 2023-10-02  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
24 2023-10-03  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
25 2023-10-04  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   0.0  10.0  10.0
26 2023-10-05  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
27 2023-10-06  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
28 2023-10-07  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
29 2023-10-08  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
30 2023-10-09  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
31 2023-10-10  1.0  2.0     1.0   0.33 2023-10-10   NaN   NaN   NaN
0  2023-01-13  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  2023-01-14  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  2023-01-15  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  2023-01-16  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
4  2023-01-17  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
5  2023-01-18  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
6  2023-01-19  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
7  2023-01-20  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
8  2023-01-21  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
9  2023-01-22  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
10 2023-01-23  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
11 2023-01-24  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
12 2023-01-25  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
13 2023-01-26  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
14 2023-01-27  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
15 2023-01-28  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
16 2023-01-29  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
17 2023-01-30  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
18 2023-01-31  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
19 2023-02-01  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
20 2023-02-02  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN  12.0   NaN
21 2023-02-03  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
22 2023-02-04  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
23 2023-02-05  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
24 2023-02-06  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
25 2023-02-07  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
26 2023-02-08  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
27 2023-02-09  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
28 2023-02-10  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   0.0  25.0  10.0
29 2023-02-11  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
30 2023-02-12  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
31 2023-02-13  2.0  8.0     1.0   0.45 2023-02-13   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Andrej Kesely, why you have for each combination of values in: id, survey 32 rows not 31 ? I need to back 31 days so each combination id, survey should has 31 rows ?

Comment: @dingaro Try to use `pd.Timedelta(days=30)` instead `pd.Timedelta(days=31)`

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

at first need dtype to datetime

```
df["event"] = pd.to_datetime(df["event"])
df["survey"] = pd.to_datetime(df["survey"])
```

there are too many solution that can solve your problem, but I think the easiest way **to match the sort order to your intent** is to split the dataframe into groups and use a loop.

```
result = []
for _, data in df.groupby(['id', 'nps']):
    s = data.iloc[0]
    days = pd.date_range(end=s['survey'] - pd.Timedelta('1day'), periods=31).drop(data['event'])[::-1]
    result.append(pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(days, columns=['event']).assign(**s.loc[:'survey'])]))
out = pd.concat(result, ignore_index=True)
```

out

```
id  nps target  score   survey  event   col1    col2    col3
0   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-25  1.0 20.0    11.0
1   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-04  0.0 10.0    10.0
2   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-09  NaN NaN NaN
3   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-08  NaN NaN NaN
4   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-07  NaN NaN NaN
5   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-06  NaN NaN NaN
6   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-05  NaN NaN NaN
7   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-03  NaN NaN NaN
8   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-02  NaN NaN NaN
9   1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-10-01  NaN NaN NaN
10  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-30  NaN NaN NaN
11  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-29  NaN NaN NaN
12  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-28  NaN NaN NaN
13  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-27  NaN NaN NaN
14  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-26  NaN NaN NaN
15  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-24  NaN NaN NaN
16  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-23  NaN NaN NaN
17  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-22  NaN NaN NaN
18  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-21  NaN NaN NaN
19  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-20  NaN NaN NaN
20  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-19  NaN NaN NaN
21  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-18  NaN NaN NaN
22  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-17  NaN NaN NaN
23  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-16  NaN NaN NaN
24  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-15  NaN NaN NaN
25  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-14  NaN NaN NaN
26  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-13  NaN NaN NaN
27  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-12  NaN NaN NaN
28  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-11  NaN NaN NaN
29  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-10  NaN NaN NaN
30  1   2   1   0.3 2023-10-10  2023-09-09  NaN NaN NaN
31  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-05-01  0.0 10.0    NaN
32  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-05-04  NaN NaN NaN
33  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-05-03  NaN NaN NaN
34  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-05-02  NaN NaN NaN
35  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-30  NaN NaN NaN
36  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-29  NaN NaN NaN
37  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-28  NaN NaN NaN
38  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-27  NaN NaN NaN
39  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-26  NaN NaN NaN
40  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-25  NaN NaN NaN
41  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-24  NaN NaN NaN
42  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-23  NaN NaN NaN
43  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-22  NaN NaN NaN
44  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-21  NaN NaN NaN
45  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-20  NaN NaN NaN
46  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-19  NaN NaN NaN
47  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-18  NaN NaN NaN
48  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-17  NaN NaN NaN
49  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-16  NaN NaN NaN
50  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-15  NaN NaN NaN
51  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-14  NaN NaN NaN
52  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-13  NaN NaN NaN
53  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-12  NaN NaN NaN
54  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-11  NaN NaN NaN
55  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-10  NaN NaN NaN
56  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-09  NaN NaN NaN
57  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-08  NaN NaN NaN
58  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-07  NaN NaN NaN
59  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-06  NaN NaN NaN
60  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-05  NaN NaN NaN
61  1   5   0   0.6 2023-05-05  2023-04-04  NaN NaN NaN
62  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-10  0.0 25.0    10.0
63  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-02  NaN 12.0    NaN
64  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-12  NaN NaN NaN
65  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-11  NaN NaN NaN
66  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-09  NaN NaN NaN
67  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-08  NaN NaN NaN
68  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-07  NaN NaN NaN
69  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-06  NaN NaN NaN
70  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-05  NaN NaN NaN
71  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-04  NaN NaN NaN
72  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-03  NaN NaN NaN
73  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-02-01  NaN NaN NaN
74  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-31  NaN NaN NaN
75  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-30  NaN NaN NaN
76  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-29  NaN NaN NaN
77  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-28  NaN NaN NaN
78  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-27  NaN NaN NaN
79  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-26  NaN NaN NaN
80  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-25  NaN NaN NaN
81  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-24  NaN NaN NaN
82  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-23  NaN NaN NaN
83  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-22  NaN NaN NaN
84  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-21  NaN NaN NaN
85  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-20  NaN NaN NaN
86  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-19  NaN NaN NaN
87  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-18  NaN NaN NaN
88  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-17  NaN NaN NaN
89  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-16  NaN NaN NaN
90  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-15  NaN NaN NaN
91  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-14  NaN NaN NaN
92  2   8   1   0.5 2023-02-13  2023-01-13  NaN NaN NaN
```

---

1-line code

```
pd.concat([pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(end=data.iloc[0]['survey'] - pd.Timedelta('1day'), periods=31).drop(data['event'])[::-1], columns=['event']).assign(**data.iloc[0].loc[:'survey'])]) for _, data in df.groupby(['id', 'nps'])], ignore_index=True)
```

---

groupby + apply

```
def func1(data):
    s = data.iloc[0]
    days = pd.date_range(end=s['survey'] - pd.Timedelta('1day'), periods=31).drop(data['event'])[::-1]
    return pd.concat([data, pd.DataFrame(days, columns=['event']).assign(**s.loc[:'survey'])])

out = df.groupby(["id", "survey"], group_keys=False, sort=False).apply(func1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Why not use `groupby.apply` rather than a `for _, data in groupby`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating those new rows in your Pandas DataFrame based on the given requirements can be done with Python. You can achieve this using the pandas library and some date calculations.

```
# Import Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta

# Create the dataframe using your data
data = [
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-09-25', 1, 20, 11),
    (1, 2, 1, 0.33, '2023-10-10', '2023-10-04', 0, 10, 10),
    (1, 5, 0, 0.58, '2023-05-05', '2023-05-01', 0, 10, None),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-10', 0, 25, 10),
    (2, 8, 1, 0.45, '2023-02-13', '2023-02-02', None, 12, None)
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df

# Convert 'event' and 'survey' columns to datetime type
df['survey'] = pd.to_datetime(df['survey'])
df['event'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event'])

# Create subset dataframe for each id, survey
survey_df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey']).reset_index(drop=True)

# Generate the date range list
date_range_list = [pd.date_range(end=survey_date - pd.Timedelta(days=1), periods=31, freq='D') for survey_date in survey_df['survey']]

# Create new data with all event dates
new_data = []

# Iterate through each row in 'survey_df' and its corresponding date range
for i, survey_date in enumerate(survey_df['survey']):
    event_dates = date_range_list[i]

    # Iterate through each date in the date range
    for event_date in event_dates:
        new_data.append([survey_df.at[i, 'id'], survey_df.at[i, 'nps'],survey_df.at[i, 'target'], survey_df.at[i, 'score'], survey_date, event_date])

# Create a new DataFrame using the collected data
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey', 'event'])

# Merge the two DataFrames and use 'combine_first' to prioritize values from 'df' if they exist
merged_df = new_df.set_index(['id', 'survey', 'event']).combine_first(df.set_index(['id', 'survey', 'event'])).reset_index()

# Reorder the columns in merged_df and sort by 'id' and 'survey'
merged_df = merged_df[['id', 'nps', 'target', 'score', 'survey', 'event', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']].sort_values(by=['id', 'survey'])

print(merged_df)
```

Print result:

```
    id  nps  target  score     survey      event  col1  col2  col3
0    1    5       0   0.58 2023-05-05 2023-04-04   NaN   NaN   NaN
1    1    5       0   0.58 2023-05-05 2023-04-05   NaN   NaN   NaN
2    1    5       0   0.58 2023-05-05 2023-04-06   NaN   NaN   NaN
3    1    5       0   0.58 2023-05-05 2023-04-07   NaN   NaN   NaN
4    1    5       0   0.58 2023-05-05 2023-04-08   NaN   NaN   NaN
..  ..  ...     ...    ...        ...        ...   ...   ...   ...
88   2    8       1   0.45 2023-02-13 2023-02-08   NaN   NaN   NaN
89   2    8       1   0.45 2023-02-13 2023-02-09   NaN   NaN   NaN
90   2    8       1   0.45 2023-02-13 2023-02-10   0.0  25.0  10.0
91   2    8       1   0.45 2023-02-13 2023-02-11   NaN   NaN   NaN
92   2    8       1   0.45 2023-02-13 2023-02-12   NaN   NaN   NaN

[93 rows x 9 columns]
```

I hope this helps, Good luck with your project!

Comment: Hey, almost perfect but you have duplicates in you output for example in id = 1, survye = 2023-10-10 and event = 2023-09-25 this line is 2 times in your output

Comment: why you have for each combination of values in: id, survey 32 rows not 31 ? I need to back 31 days so each combination id, survey should has 31 rows

Comment: Hello, my apologies for the duplications; they were caused by having the same survey dates. I've already addressed the issue. Thank you for bringing it to my attention!